Creating a Twitter Bot for Continuous Posting Across Multiple Accounts
I'm working on developing a Twitter bot that continuously posts throughout the day across multiple accounts. The bot should log in to each account, make a post, log out, and then move to the next account until all accounts have been utilized, before starting the process again.
I've already set up the basic web automation using Selenium in Python, but I'm seeking guidance on implementing the following aspects:
How can I efficiently manage the login and logout process for multiple Twitter accounts to ensure smooth operation throughout the day?
What strategies can I employ to handle potential errors or interruptions during the posting process, such as network issues or temporary bans?
Is there a recommended approach or library for managing a queue of posts across multiple accounts to ensure a fair distribution and prevent overloading any single account?
Are there any existing projects, tutorials, or resources that provide insights or code examples for implementing this type of bot effectively?
I appreciate any advice, tips, or references to relevant documentation that can help me achieve my goal. Thank you for your assistance!

You should check the Twitter API Documentation.
